# iOS import causing tons of errors?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to set up a menu in my cocos2d game and whenever I import Game.h I end up with over 200 errors.

It's a cocos2d app with box2d, I'm not sure why it's throwing all these errors though- the game was running perfectly before I swapped loading the Game scene for the MainMenu scene initially. The line of code I'm running is

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [Game node]];
```

The import of 'Game' causes the errors. Can anyone give me an idea about this?

Some information that may be helpful... I originally created the project loading into Game.m but switched it to MainMenu and then import Game.h into MainMenu to access the object.

ANY insight is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't paste the specific errors but this sound like a circular dependancy problem.

My guess is that you have to forward declare `Game` class where you use it.

Try to add

```
@class Game;
```

at the beginning of `MainMenu.h`.

If my guess is correct you are actually importing `MainMenu.h` from `Game.h` too, that's why the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks Jack! Forwarding Game seemed to work! Although I wasn't importing MainMenu.h from Game.h- weird. Anyways, I'm wondering if you could help eliminate a warning that's showing now saying that

"Receiver Game is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist"

Answer (score 0):

you need to import Game.h somewhere; the @class declaration will fix circular dependencies but is not a replacement for an import. be sure your game's header is included on the `.m` or elsewhere that you are actually working with the Game class